# How to plot a triangle given specific positions in R?

Tags: r, plot

Given the point positions of the triangle are:

```
c(0,0)
c(1,0)
c(0,1)
```

How can I get a triangle with green color in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For vectors:

```
x <- c(0, 1, 0)
y <- c(0, 0, 1)
```

Create a plot:

```
plot(x, y)
```

You can use `polygon()` to add the triangle:

```
polygon(x, y)
```

The result is:

[image]

To create a green border use:

```
polygon(x, y, border = 'green')
```

[image]

To create a green area use:

```
polygon(x, y, col = 'green')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
plot(c(0,0),c(0,1),type="l",xlim=c(0,1),axes=F,col=3,lwd=2,xlab = "",ylab="")
lines(c(0,1),c(1,0),col=3,lwd=2)
lines(c(1,0),c(0,0),col=3,lwd=2)
box()
```

col=3  makes the lines' colour green. lwd=2 increases line width.